# How to train a ML Model for detecting duplicates without having data sets

Tags: python, machine-learning, duplicates, abap

I am currently working on my master thesis. My topic is the development of a duplicate checking system in ABAP for a customer in the SAP environment. Up to now, the whole thing works in such a way that if the checking system does not know exactly whether an incoming data record is a duplicate or not, a clerk intervenes and makes the final decision. The clerk is to be "replaced by a machine learning model", which is to be located on a Python server, so that the clerk intervenes less in the process and becomes more and more of an "AI trainer". The communication between the duplicate checking system and the ML model is done by a REST API. The ML-model should decide whether incoming data records are duplicates or not.

My first problem is that I don't have any training data to create an ML model. The second problem is that I still do not know exactly what my training data might look like from the structure. It is possible to get client data records from the client, but for various reasons this is quite unlikely. Is there a way to generate "synthetic data" to create an ML model? What could it look like for my application? Which tools could I use to make my work a little easier?

Many greetings

Comment: how does a clerk decide if a "data record" is a duplicate?

Comment: When he/she sees both data sets at once

Comment: yes, but the clerk is going to compare something. why dont you try to implement that? You can then use it to generate your training data, which of course doesn't make sense anymore because you already have a working duplicate checker.

Comment: You mean implementing the logic, how the clerk decides, as a ML model or as static functions?

Comment: as a static function. It also was a subtle hint that your approach doesnt make sense

Comment: Most of the work will be done by the duplicate checking system in ABAP, where most static functions are integrated, but there may be cases where the checking system fails. This is exactly where the ML model comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

When you don't have any real-world data and how humans classified it, then you can not train a ML system to classify real-world data.

What you can do is train a system with data you generated and classified in a way you *believe* to be similar to what the program might encounter in the wild. This would allow you to try your methodology and see if it works at all. But if you want to create an ML model which is actually useful in the real world, you need to repeat the training process with real-world data.

Comment: Seriously, please adhere to Philipp’s advice. I saw too many machine learning projects fail because people believed you could do it without data. Would you trust a self-driving car that never once “saw” a street? Or an automatic cancer detection algorithm that never once sampled some real life data? In your case, do you have even a clue what you are looking for? Is it typos? Alternative name spellings? Intentional fraud? As Philipp explains, you can use generated data to validate the code technically works, but you shouldn’t even start considering using it for the actual training.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of variability with what your data COULD be. You need to narrow down with what it will look like.

You can always create random data:

```
>>> N = 5
>>> import random
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.random((N,N))
```

Create yourself a whole bunch of random arrays, but then copy one, and then you can test whether you can catch whether it is duplicate or not?

Comment: But the random function returns random floats. How can I use them for my use case?

Comment: I am confused why this would be a problem as a 'test' dataset.